# I can't connect my MySQL Database with jdbc in logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I want to input some data from MySQL database with logstash.

Here is my `jdbc.conf`

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://111.11.11.111:3306/dbname"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "****"
    statement => "SELECT title from test"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => json }
}
```

`username`, `password`, `host`, `dbname` and `column_name` are fake. and `output` is just for testing.
My database is on the same VPS server.

`--configtest` is cleared. However, I got this error.

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /opt/logstash/bin/config/jdbc.conf
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Pipeline aborted due to error {
    :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", 
    :backtrace=>[
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.1.0/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:159:in `prepare_jdbc_connection'", 
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.1.0/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:187:in `register'", 
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:330:in `start_inputs'", 
        "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'",
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:329:in `start_inputs'", 
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:180:in `start_workers'", 
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", 
        "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"],
     :level=>:error}
stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

I got the `LogStash::ConfigurationError`. Waht's wrong with my config?

Comment: According to the error message and the fact that the `--configtest` passed, I'm guessing that Logstash cannot connect to your database for some reason.

Comment: yes, I want to know the reason of "for some reason"...

Comment: Try running Logstash in debug mode by adding `--debug` to the run command, you might get  some more info.

Comment: Is the mysql url accessible from a non root process? I.e. can logstash actually get to `111.11.11.111:3306`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.
It was just a bug of jdbc-driver.
While I was facing to the bug, I was using ver5.1.40 via the mysql webpage.
After I changed it to mysql-connector-java-5.1.17 via yum, It does work.